# Start detached screen over SSH with bash command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, gnu-screen

I am attempting to start a screen session in detached mode over SSH that executes a bash command inside screen...

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 "screen -wipe"

sleep 1

ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 screen -dmS session1 bash -c 'weechat --dir ircdir'

sleep 1

ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 -t "screen -x session1"
```

however, the following line does not seem to be working in the script, however, it works from the command prompt, any ideas?

```
ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 screen -dmS session1 bash -c 'weechat --dir ircdir'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `set -e` together with `ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 "screen -wipe"` is the issue.

If there is no screen session `ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 "screen -wipe"` will fail and return exit code 1.

Then, when `set -e` is set it means the script will exit immediately on a non-zero status.
[Bash - set](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)

I think either:

- skip exit on non-zero status, I.e change the 'set -e'
- make sure that there is a screen session available before you run the script
- skip the `screen -wipe`
- other solution that match your requirements

For debug and trying you can temporary change `set -e` to `set -ex`.
Then you will see that the script will never comes to this row.
`ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 screen -dmS session1 bash -c 'weechat --dir ircdir'`

Additionally, as test to make it run, change `set -e` to `set -x`.
Then you will see it run and `ssh jlroberts@10.0.0.202 screen -dmS session1 bash -c 'weechat --dir ircdir'` will be in the debug message.

Comment: oh that makes a lot of sense, I have set -e and set -x confused...